# setTitle(string) - Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I have a class that indirectly inherits from `MainScreen`, and `setTitle(string)` isn't working. Below is my hierarchy:

```
public class Class1 extends MainScreen { 
    super( MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR );
     ... 
} 
public class Class2 extends Class1 { 
    setTitle("Hello World"); 
     ...
}
```

I have also tried `super.setTitle(string)`.

It compiles correctly, but no title shows on the screen.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: What do you see? Empty title? could you check that you don't call `setTitle` somewhere else?

Comment: Good call. Apparently I was calling `setTitle("");` in a Class1 method. I've been staring at the screen too long, haha. 

If you make it an answer, ill mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment transformed to answer:

I don't remember any issues with this method and it's quite straight forward.
Most probably you call `setTitle` somewhere else. Please search your code.